# Visual Basic .NET Project - Airline System

Tags: vb.net

I want the 32 radiobuttons individually be able to be linked to a database when I click the 1 button which says "Submit". Meaning when I select 1 radio button and i click the submit button I would like to have a msg saying booking confirmed or something and when i click the submit button it stores it in the database. I have tried to develop something similar to this I tried making normal textboxs being able to store it in a database.  How do I link MS Access to Visual Basic in order for the radio buttons to work? Would the Primary Key be the Field called Seats if thats where I want to store the data from that field in the table? 
The Form comprises of:

1. PictureBox - which is an image that is a layout seating plan on a plane.
2. 32 RadioButtons

1 Radio Button = 1 seat ideally

3. 1 Button - When the user has chosen a seat they want they should click a button called "Submit". When the button is clicked I want the seat that the user has clicked on be able to be stored into a table within a database. Once the seat has been stored the next user after the previous one isn't allowed to select that particular seat that someone else has picked. I want this to be a looping process for 32 seats on the airplane until the plane is full.

Would I use a While loop for this to work or would I use an If statement and keep on saying ElseIF in my code?

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for all radio buttons set seat number as text and then assign the same event handler for `CheckedChanged` event of all radio buttons and write the following code within that event handler.

```
Private Sub RadioButton1_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RadioButton1.CheckedChanged, RadioButton2.CheckedChanged, ...
        Dim RB As RadioButton = sender
        If RB.Checked Then
             'write the code to save the seat number i.e. RB.Text to database
        End If
End Sub
```